# Plugin options not appearing on options page using tabbed navigation

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, plugin-options

I've modified the plugin options page for my plugin to use tabs, using the existing WordPress system for this. However, The actual options are not appearing on the screen - just the tabs and the "Save Changes" button.

[Here is the code for the options page](https://github.com/cconover/cc-wp-buffer/blob/269e6c3f485781b648b9048bc5d9ebe9e3cd9d29/admin/cc-wp-buffer-admin.php#L264-L671).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I was referencing the wrong page ID in my add_settings_section() call.